# Changing the SharePoint default title text (legend) in SharePoint 2013

Tags: page-layout, 2013, theme

In the default theme for SharePoint 2013 (seattle), on the top left corner, there is a small amount of Text that says "SharePoint". I wanted to change it to show the name of the company instead of sharepoint, but I've been unable to do it.

I tried modifying the theme, but there is nothing like it on the layout. That part of the website is being rendered by the server, not the template.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the content of that zone through PowerShell, it's managed by the SuiteBarBrandingElementHtml property on the WebApplication object :

```
$app = Get-SPWebApplication -Identity "your-web-application-url"
$app.SuiteBarBrandingElementHtml = "<div class='ms-core-brandingText'>Your Company Name</div>"
$app.Update()
```

Comment: http://www.topsharepoint.com/change-sharepoint-2013-title